# [yocto-Jethro]Neet to compile

Tags: compilation, yocto, libtiff

I am stucking for compiling for libtiff
i am sorry for inconvient because of second time to meet yocto. i am lost.

on reading a document yocto 2.o jethro
5.8.6. Extra Development/Debug Package Cleanup¶

The following recipes have had extra dev/dbg packages removed:

"  acl   apmd    aspell    attr    augeas    bzip2    cogl    curl   elfutils    gcc-target    libgcc    libtool    libxmu    opkg    pciutils    rpm    sysfsutils    tiff    xz "

All of the above recipes now conform to the standard packaging scheme where a single -dev, -dbg, and -staticdev package exists per recipe.

Do you know how to compilile tiff ?

Thank so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

libtiff is part of oe-core, so just 'bitbake tiff'.

Comment: Thank so much in advance,  Can you know how to compile without command line?